# Strongly Typed include not available

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have upgrade from EF 4.0 to EF 4.2

My context inherits from `ObjectContext`.

The strongly typed `Include` method (to include linked entities in the results) is not available on my entities sets (that inherit from `ObjectSet`).

Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "include"? ARe you referring to the types generated from the model (`.edmx`)?

Comment: I mean the method Include that enable eager loading

Comment: I've tried to clarify (and formatted).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It lives in using System.Data.Entity; and is an extension method for IQueryable
Try `using System.Data.Entity` and see if it's available.